# Best way to store metadata for a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

We have an app deployed at Heroku using a Postgres database and, as we scale our app, we wonder what is the best way to store large amounts of data. It seems quite unfeasible to do so in the current scheme and we wonder whether we should use HDFS or related technologies.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size and type of data. 
Are we talking a few GB? a few TB? a PB?
Would the data need to query the data frequently or mostly for archived purposes?
For some data you are only interested in daily, weekly, monthly summaries, so building such summaries and then archiving the data to s3 or glaciers can work wonders. 
If you are familiar with Postgresql, you also can leverage your inhouse expertise and feel at home using Amazon RedShift.